# KeyCloak with AzureAD

Tags: java, keycloak, keycloak-services, keycloak-rest-api, keycloak-connect

I'm trying to configure my environment in keycloak to authenticate with azure active directory according to the documentation ( https://www.keycloak.org/getting-started ) with an image already created in docker, I managed to do the configuration using IdentityProvider but it always presents me with a call back after being authenticated on a page, but I need an endpoint so I can login as if it were an LDAP but using Azure

my configs:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u8wvX.png)

Comment: I don't think you can use Azure AD with user federation (ldap). Identity provider should work fine though, what is the problem with the callback?

Comment: What is the problem with the callback and what endpoint are you referring?